# inconsistent string sorting with template method

Tags: c++, string, templates, sorting

I am trying to do a template function that sorts 3 elements,
numbers(int, double) work fine but string's do not behave as expected

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename TYPE>
void sort3(TYPE n1, TYPE n2, TYPE n3) {
    TYPE arr[3];
    arr[0] = n1;
    arr[1] = n2;
    arr[2] = n3;
    sort(arr, arr + 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sort3("B", "Z", "A");
    sort3(10.2, 99.0, 1.9);
    sort3(200, 50, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

gives me the following output:

> A Z B
>
> 1.9 10.2 99
>
> 1 50 200

to my understanding `sort3("B", "Z", "A");` should give me `A B Z`
it is not OS specific since it gives me the same result in [online compiler](http://ideone.com/7Q402J)
what is happening there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131491/why-isnt-stdsort-alphabetizing-an-array-of-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because what you are passing are string literals, which are arrays of characters. When passing them as arguments to a function, **arrays decay to pointers**. Therefore, what you are sorting is the *value* of those pointers (and not the strings they are pointing to).

Try this:

```
#include <string>

// ...

sort3(std::string("B"), std::string("Z"), std::string("A"));
```

This works because an overload of `operator <` for `std::string` exists, and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses `operator <` to compare elements when a custom comparator is not passed as a third argument (which is your case).

Comment: can I create a generic comparator that I can pass `"a"` instead of  `string("a")` ?

Comment: @Borian: Yes, you could do that. Just define a functor that has two call operators, one for `const char*` that would construct `std::string` from the operands and compare those objects, and another operator template that uses `<` for any type

Comment: @Andy Prowl: What do you think about a "specialised" (surly there is a more correct name for that) template function for const char *, calling the  sort3 with strings?

Comment: @hr_117: You probably mean an *overload* of `sort3` that accepts three `const char*` and calls the generic `sort3` this way: `sort3(std::string(arg1), std::string(arg2), std::string(arg3));`. Yes, that is also a possibility :)

Answer (score 3):

You end up comparing the pointers and not the actual string contents.  One way to solve it would be like this:

```
sort3(std::string("B"), std::string("Z"), std::string("A"));
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you like to stay with calling sort3  with `const char*` you can add a "specialised" template:

```
template<>
void sort3(const char* n1, const char* n2,const char* n3) {
    sort3( string(n1), string(n2), string(n3));
}
```

With this  `sort3("B", "Z", "A");`  also will work.

But your question "what is happening there ?" is already answered by Andy Prowl.